# MongoDB aggregation wtih distinct value in Java?

Tags: mongodb, spring-boot, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework, aggregation

I am trying to get the latest entered document based upon a unique ID. Here is the collection

```
{
        "_id" : "535f5d074f075c37fff4cc74",
        "senderId" : 8989898,
        "receiverId" : 8686868,
        "channelId" : "909090",
        "createdAt": 1
}
{
        "_id" : "535f5d074f075c37fff4cc74",
        "senderId" : 8989898,
        "receiverId" : 8686868,
        "channelId" : "909090"
        "createdAt": 2
}
{
        "_id" : "535f5d074f075c37fff4cc74",
        "senderId" : 8989898,
        "receiverId" : 10101010,
        "channelId" : "919191"
        "createdAt": 3
}
```

The result will be :

```
{
        "_id" : "535f5d074f075c37fff4cc74",
        "senderId" : 8989898,
        "receiverId" : 8686868,
        "channelId" : "909090"
        "createdAt": 2
}
{
        "_id" : "535f5d074f075c37fff4cc74",
        "senderId" : 8989898,
        "receiverId" : 10101010,
        "channelId" : "919191"
        "createdAt": 3
}
```

Providing the elements with distinct `channelId` keyword and the latest created with in `channelId`.

I tried the following approach:

```
Aggregation aggregation = Aggregation.newAggregation(
            Aggregation.sort(Sort.Direction.DESC, Constant.CREATED_AT),
            Aggregation.group(Constant.CHANNEL_ID));

return mongoTemplate.aggregate(aggregation, "tbl_message", Messages.class)
            .getMappedResults()
            .stream()
            .distinct()
            .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

The above code is just providing me distinct channelId (s) in the entire collection. How can I correct the above statement as per the requirements?

Answer (score 1):

Your example documents are invalid because you have a unique key violation on field `_id`.  For this reason, I have renamed the field to simply `id`.

**Sample Test Data**

```
db.collection.insertMany([
{
        "id" : "535f5d074f075c37fff4cc74",
        "senderId" : 8989898,
        "receiverId" : 8686868,
        "channelId" : "909090",
        "createdAt": 1
},
{
        "id" : "535f5d074f075c37fff4cc74",
        "senderId" : 8989898,
        "receiverId" : 8686868,
        "channelId" : "909090",
        "createdAt": 2
},
{
        "id" : "535f5d074f075c37fff4cc74",
        "senderId" : 8989898,
        "receiverId" : 10101010,
        "channelId" : "919191",
        "createdAt": 3
}])
```

Aside from that, I think you were pretty close, but your `GROUP BY` clause needs some changes.  Here is what I believe to be a working version...

**Code Example**

```
package test.barry;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        com.mongodb.client.MongoClient client = connectToReplicaSet();
        com.mongodb.client.MongoDatabase db = client.getDatabase("barrydb");
        com.mongodb.client.MongoCollection<org.bson.Document> collection = db.getCollection("collection");

        com.mongodb.client.AggregateIterable<org.bson.Document> iterable1 = collection.aggregate(
            java.util.Arrays.asList(
                com.mongodb.client.model.Aggregates.sort(com.mongodb.client.model.Sorts.orderBy(com.mongodb.client.model.Sorts.ascending("id"), com.mongodb.client.model.Sorts.ascending("channelId"), com.mongodb.client.model.Sorts.descending("createdAt"))),
                com.mongodb.client.model.Aggregates.group(
                    new org.bson.BsonDocument("id", new org.bson.BsonString("$id")).append("channelId", new org.bson.BsonString("$channelId")),
                        com.mongodb.client.model.Accumulators.first("senderId", "$senderId"),
                        com.mongodb.client.model.Accumulators.first("receiverId", "$receiverId"),
                        com.mongodb.client.model.Accumulators.first("createdAt", "$createdAt"),
                        com.mongodb.client.model.Accumulators.first("originalId", "$_id")
                ),
                com.mongodb.client.model.Aggregates.project(
                    com.mongodb.client.model.Projections.fields(
                        com.mongodb.client.model.Projections.computed("_id", "$originalId"),
                        com.mongodb.client.model.Projections.computed("id", "$_id.id"),
                        com.mongodb.client.model.Projections.include("senderId", "receiverId"),
                        com.mongodb.client.model.Projections.computed("channelId", "$_id.channelId"),
                        com.mongodb.client.model.Projections.include("createdAt")
                    )
                )
            )
        );

        // AUTO-CLOSABLE TRY
        try(com.mongodb.client.MongoCursor<org.bson.Document> cursor1 = iterable1.iterator())
        {
            while (cursor1.hasNext())
            {
                org.bson.Document queriedDocument1 = cursor1.next();
                System.out.println(String.format("queriedDocument1: %s", queriedDocument1));
            }
        }
    }

    private static com.mongodb.client.MongoClient connectToReplicaSet() {
        java.util.ArrayList<com.mongodb.ServerAddress> hosts = new java.util.ArrayList<com.mongodb.ServerAddress>();
        hosts.add(new com.mongodb.ServerAddress("localhost", 50011));
        hosts.add(new com.mongodb.ServerAddress("localhost", 50012));
        hosts.add(new com.mongodb.ServerAddress("localhost", 50013));

        com.mongodb.MongoCredential mongoCredential = com.mongodb.MongoCredential.createScramSha256Credential("testuser", "admin", "mysecret".toCharArray());

        com.mongodb.MongoClientSettings mongoClientSettings = com.mongodb.MongoClientSettings.builder()
            .applyToClusterSettings(clusterSettingsBuilder -> clusterSettingsBuilder.hosts(hosts).requiredReplicaSetName("replSet"))
            .credential(mongoCredential)
            .writeConcern(com.mongodb.WriteConcern.MAJORITY)
            .readConcern(com.mongodb.ReadConcern.MAJORITY)
            .readPreference(com.mongodb.ReadPreference.primary())
            .retryWrites(true)
            .build();

        com.mongodb.client.MongoClient client = com.mongodb.client.MongoClients.create(mongoClientSettings);

        return client;
    }
}
```

**Aggregation Explained**

There are 3 stages to this aggregation

1. Sort
2. Group
3. Project

The `$sort` stage will sort by field `id` ascending, then by field `channelId` ascending, then by `createdAt` descending.  This will kind of group the records logically together in the desired order.

The `$group` stage will group by `id` and `channelId`.  Because the documents have already been sorted in the first stage we can simply take the first occurrence of a group and retain the other fields (via accumulator `$first`).

The grouping stage leaves the documents in a less-than-desirable shape.  To fix the shape, use a `$project` to put the documents back into desired shape.

**Example output**

```
queriedDocument1: Document{{senderId=8989898, receiverId=10101010, createdAt=3, _id=616d9387719033ca154188a2, id=535f5d074f075c37fff4cc74, channelId=919191}}
queriedDocument1: Document{{senderId=8989898, receiverId=8686868, createdAt=2, _id=616d9387719033ca154188a1, id=535f5d074f075c37fff4cc74, channelId=909090}}
```

**Conclusion**

It appears there is no additional sorting requirement for the final output, so the natural order where 3 arrives before 2 is OK.  If needed, an additional `$sort` stage could be applied for the final output.